# Why aren't my clothes assigned weights? Why can't I assign loose geometry to a bone?

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting

I'm currently rigging a clothed character model, but I've encountered some issues. The character and the clothing are all one object. However, with automatic weight pairing, the clothing seems to be ignored.

[image: The weight painting of a breast bone, with no clothing above it painted.]

Also, when I select loose mesh to assign to a bone, blender simply won't do it.

[image: A selection of loose mesh to assign to the head bone.]

I'll hit "Assign", but the selected faces won't actually get assigned to the bone I've selected.

[image: The vertex groups menu.]

What's causing this?

Answer (score 0):

i am in the same hussle, even if you have a bone and a vertex group you hit assign and nothing happends. So frustating, a solution to me is isolate the mesh to an OBJECT (i dont want to do this but...) and select armature, then bone, then object and then parent to bone.

I KNOW that it should work as you explain but i dont know IT dosent, and it is from various version. It is a bug?

Comment: ok ok ok , i found a simple solution that implicates not to isolated mesh. Just Check that the bone has the deformation enabled(I know, it seems stupid), why this, because i disabled one bone and i didnt knew that i was copyng one that has deform disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by separating the clothing from the body, parenting the skeleton to the clothing with automatic weights, and joining the body and the clothing back together!